# Is there a fast signature scheme homomorphic over $GF(2^b)$ with $b > 1$?

Tags: signature, homomorphic-signatures

Is there a signature scheme that given $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_p^k$ and signatures $S(x)$ and $S(y)$ allows any linear combination of $x, y$ to be successfully verified, and nothing else?

I'm aware of schemes where $p = 2$, where 'linear combination' just means XOR, but I'm interested in bigger fields, in particular $GF(256)$, where you could prove the authenticity of $c_1x + c_2y$ with $c_1, c_2 \in GF(256)$ given just $S(x)$ and $S(y)$.

I only care about authenticity - what is being signed is not secret.